# Gromov-Hausdorff limits of 2-dimensional Riemannian surfaces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, alexandrov-geometry

Let $\{M_i\}$ be a sequence of 2-dimensional orientable closed surfaces of genus $g$ with smooth Riemannian metrics with the Gauss curvature at least $-1$ and diameter at most $D$. By the Gromov compactness theorem, one can choose a subsequence converging in the Gromov-Hausdorff sense to a compact Alexandrov space with curvature at least $-1$ and Hausdorff dimension 0,1,or 2. One can show (see below) that if $g\geq 2$ then the limit space cannot be a point, thus the dimension of the limit space is at least 1 (while for $g=0,1$ it can be 0).

Let us assume that the limit space has dimension 1. Then it is either circle or segment.

**Whether these both possibilities (circle and segment) can be obtained in the limit?**

**ADDED:** It is not hard to see that one can get segment for $g=0$ and circle for $g=1$. I suspect (but cannot prove) that for $g\geq 2$ and $g=0$ one *cannot* get circle in the limit. In fact I do not even know whether in the case $g\geq 2$ a 2-dimensional limit is the only possibility.

**UPDATE:** Based on the answer by Igor Belegradek, let me summarize the situation. Let $\{M_i\}$ be a sequence of genus $g$ orientable closed surfaces with Riemannian metrics with Gauss curvature at least -1 which converges in the Gromov-Hausdorff sense to an Alexandrov space $X$.

1) If $g=0$ then $X$ is either a point, or a segment, or $X$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$ (by Perelman stability theorem), and all the three cases are possible.

2) If $g=1$ then $X$ is either a point, or a circle $S^1$, or homeomorphic to the 2-torus, and all the three cases are possible.

3) If $g\geq 2$ then $\dim X=2$ and hence $X$ is homeomorphic to an orientable genus $g$ closed surface.

**ADDED:** Let me add a proof that if $g\geq 2$ then a point cannot be the limiting space. Indeed otherwise we would have $d_i:=diam(M_i)\to 0$. Let us divide the metric of $M_i$ by $d_i$ and denote the new metric space by $N_i$. Then the sectional curvature of $N_i$ is at least $-d_i^2$ and diameter 1.

By the Gauss-Bonnet $$4\pi(1-g)=\int_{N_i}K\geq -d_i^2vol(N_i).$$
By the Bishop inequality $vol(N_i)$ is bounded from above. Hence the right hand side in the above inequality tends to 0. Hence $1-g\geq 0$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: If the limit is smooth (e.g. a circle), then by the Yamaguchi's fibration theorem $M_i$ is a fiber bundle over the limit (for large $i$). The only orientable closed surface that fibers over the circle is the torus (because the fiber is also a circle for dimension reasons). Reading Yamaguchi's more recent papers on low-dimensional collapse will help you understand the case when the limit is an interval.

Comment: Are your surfaces compact? You did not say this. If con-compact are permitted, take cylinders $I\times S$ where $I$ is an interval and $S$ is a small circle, and equip with the standard metric of curvature $0$. You obtain a segment in the limit.

Comment: I wish to add that if you wish to black box the collapsing theory (and you shouldn't!) you could just multiply your collapsing sequence by a circle, so that you now have a sequence of $3$-manifolds collapsing to a cylinder. Then Shioya-Yamaguchi's paper formally applies, see http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1090347524. Of course this is an overkill.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: Thanks, corrected.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: I am not sure, what is the conclusion of the use of the collapsing theory?

Comment: I suggest you look at the paper by Shioya-Yamaguchi I mentioned and get the conclusion yourself. I cannot help wondering how one can think about these matters and did not know about Yamaguchi's fibration theorem. I think some reading is in order.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: I agree that some reading would be very helpful to me and I would greatly appreciate a reference. I just wanted to make sure that the above reference does contain the answer to my question since I am wondering about a specific fact rather than about more general question "how one can think about these matters". Anyway many thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Igor, in the end Yamaguchi is not needed for the solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if the limit is a circle, then by the Yamaguchi fibration theorem, $M_i$ fibers over the circle, and hence it is a torus (or Klein bottle in the non-orientable case).

If the limit is a segment, then $M_i$ is $S^2$ for all large $i$. One (somewhat heavy handed) way to see this is to apply Corollary 0.4 of Shioya-Yamaguchi's [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1090347524). 
Indeed, the product of $M_i$ and a unit circle, collapses to the cylinder. Hence in Corollary 0.4 we have $g=0$ and $k=2$. Hence for large $i$ the fundamental group of $M_i\times S^1$ is a free product of $\mathbb Z$ and finitely many finite cyclic groups. Such a group cannot have a center unless all the finite cyclic groups are trivial. The circle factor of  $M_i\times S^1$ is central in the fundamental group, so $\pi_1(M_i\times S^1)=\mathbb Z$. Hence $M_i$ is a sphere (for large $i$).

This argument uses orientability of $M_i$ because Shioya-Yamaguchi only deal with orientable manifolds.

Comment: Very nice but I wonder if there might be a straightforward argument using Gauss-Bonnet in the 2-dimensional case.

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot. Though I agree with the comment by Mikhail Katz...

Comment: @MikhailKatz: On Gauss-Bonnet, what one has to rule out is small handles converging to points. One hopes that in the process curvature must tend to $-\infty$. If the handle is attached along a flat cylinder, then this seems doable: simply double along the boundary of the cylinder and argue that a closed hyperbolic surface cannot collapse to a point (which still requires more than Gauss-Bonnet, as far as I can see). Now in general the handle need not be attached along a flat cylinder and the curvature may go to $+\infty$ on the attaching region. Then I am not sure how to isolate that handle..

Comment: @MikhailKatz: May I add also a simpler comment, though it might be obvious for experts. In order to exclude the case of the limiting space to be a point when $g\geq 2$, one has to use Gauss-Bonnet combined with the Bishop inequality. But the case of segment seems to be less elementary.

Comment: @semyonalesker: would you add the Gauss-Bonnet/Bishop argument (by editing your original question)?

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: Done.

Comment: Igor, this is very nice, but the set of tools you use seems very specific. What about the following problem: is the set of all compact manifolds of a fixed dimension, upper bounded (negative) curvature and upper bounded diameter closed in the HG topology?

Comment: @user89334: it always is better to ask a separate question (rather than ask in the comments). In this case the answer is no: start with your favorite closed negatively curved manifold and create a sequence  scaling the metric by $1/i$. The limit is a point and the curvature tends to $-\infty$ so the negative upper curvature bound is there but the limit is of different dimension.

Comment: I asked this here because this is by-passing and I am not motivated enough to make a too big deal out of this question. As for the question, I meant that the curveture bound is LOWER, as iin the original 2-dim question. Sorry for the mistake and please don't bother with this too much. Just my curiosity.

Comment: @user89334: still the set is not closed: rescaling a flat torus exactly as above gives a point in the limit while the curvature is zero. More importantly one gets many singular limits spaces.

Comment: Thanks, Igor. I am not sorry for not making it a separate question...

Answer (score 10):

Consider a shortest closed geodesic $\gamma$ on the surface of length sys, and the normal exponential map of $\gamma$. Using the lower curvature bound, we obtain an upper bound on the total area as $\text{sys}\cdot \sinh(D)$ where $D$ is the diameter. This follows just by applying Rauch bounds on Jacobi fields (this is an ingredient in the proof of Toponogov). Therefore the systole is bounded below by $ \frac{\text{area}}{\sinh D}$ and the area is bounded below by Gauss-Bonnet. Furthermore the filling radius is bounded below by the 1/6 of the systole by Gromov's inequality. The least Gromov-Hausdorff distance to a graph is bounded below by the filling radius. We therefore get a quantitative lower bound and not merely nonexistence of Yamaguchi-type collapse.

This proves that hyperbolic surfaces of curvature bounded below by $-1$ with diameter bounded above by $D$ cannot collapse so that a Gromov-Hausdorff limit is necessarily 2-dimensional.

For more details see https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.06782

Comment: Unfortunately I am unfamiliar with some of the background you use. What statement exactly you proved?

Comment: @sva, which concepts are you not familiar with?

Comment: Systole and filling radius. Also apparently you use their relation to the Gromov-Hausdorff distance (to a graph?). BTW in your statement should one add the condition that the genus of the surfaces in at least 2?

Comment: The systole is the least length of a noncontractible loop on the surface $M$. The filling radius of $M$ is defined as the least epsilon such that the inclusion of $M$ in its epsilon-neighborhood sends the fundamental homology class of $M$ to zero.  Here the embedding is in the space of bounded functions on $M$ which sends a point to the distance function from that point. Actually this stage can be bypassed and one can show directly an inequality between the systole and the $(n-1)$-diameter.

Comment: @sva, the argument only works for hyperbolic surfaces (hence genus at least 2) since otherwise Gauss-Bonnet does not give a lower bound for the area.

Answer (score 8):

I remembered another reason why closed surfaces of negative Euler characteristic cannot collapse under a lower bound on sectional curvature.

Much more is true: if a sequence of $n$-dimensional closed manifolds $M_i$ of Ricci curvature $\ge -k^2$ Gromov-Hausdorff converges to a compact space of (Hausdorff) dimension $<n$, then the simplical volume of $M_i$ is zero for large $i$.

Indeed, on the bottom of p.244 of of Gromov's [Volume and bounded cohomology](http://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/PDF/7[35].pdf) he shows that a lower Ricci curvature bound implies that the simplicial volume is bounded above in terms of volume and the dimension. If a sequence of manifolds converges to a space of dimension $<n$ under the lower Ricci bound, then
their volume goes to zero; this is due to Colding, as mentioned e.g. on p.91 of 
[Aspects of Ricci Curvature.](http://library.msri.org/books/Book30/files/colding.pdf)

The simplicial volume of a closed surface of negative Euler charactersistic $\chi$ is $2|\chi|$, see p.217 in Gromov's paper, so it cannot collapse under a lower curvature bound. There are of course many high-dimensional manifolds of nonzero simplicial volume.